# OpenMDAO Specifying DOEDriver Number of Processors

Tags: python, parallel-processing, openmdao

I am trying to use the in-built DOEDriver in OpenMDAO. I know there is a setting called `procs_per_model` which determines the number of processors given to the model to run. However, is there a way to set the max number of processors that the DOE itself can use? E.g. I have 10 cores on my machine, but I only want to use 8. Is there a way to set the DOEDriver up so that it can run 8 cases at a time instead of 10 (i.e. call my model 8 times independently to run and each model run is only using one processor).

I was trying to do this by setting `max_procs` when adding a subsystem, however I think that has the same effect as `procs_per_model` in that it is just limiting the number of processors each model run can use.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want to limit the number of processes that MPI can spawn. You would do that by the way you activate the python interpreter with mpi:

```
mpirun -n 8 with DOEDriver(run_parallel=True)
```

Comment: Is there no way to get OpenMDAO to use Python multiprocessing or is the only choice MPI?

Comment: OpenMDAO as of V3.26.0 doesn't support multiprocessing parallelism